# Glass/ refraction image effect HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, effect, aero-glass

I am fairly new to all this, so, please bear with me.

I am struggling to achieve an image effect, similar to refraction, caused by rounded glass. I understand that the easiest method would be to use  and to learn JS, which would ultimately solve all of my problems; however, I have been working on a workaround, which is why I am here.

So, the effect I am trying to replicate is something that SKY did a while ago. [Here is the link.](http://web.archive.org/web/20160115102901/https://www.sky.com/) I understand that they will be using a canvas and controlling it all from there.

The idea that I had was, to use a background image, then an SVG mask of the same background image, move the second background image down 5-10px and increase the size by 2-3%, then add filter:blur(3px). I have a second image of the logo I am trying to use with already has a 'glass' look to it, so, that solves the reflections.

The bit I am struggling with, is the SVG mask. I can't seem to get it to show the background image properly, or line up with the logo.

Here is what I have so far. (please excuse the poor coding, I am still learning)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin:0;
                padding: 0;
                background-image:url(http://jforthdesigns.co.uk/images/BG002.jpg);
                background-attachment: fixed;
                background-position: center;
                width:100%;
                margin:0;
                height: 3000px;
            }
            .logo {
                width:50%;
                position:absolute;
                top: 350px;
                left: 25%;
                right:25%;
                clear:none;
            }
            #wrapper {
                text-align: center;
                width: 100%;
                padding-top: 300px;
            }
            #image {
                mask: url(#mask);
                -webkit-mask: url(http://jforthdesigns.co.uk/images/mask.svg);
            }
            .st0 {
                fill:#000000;
                stroke:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <img src="http://jforthdesigns.co.uk/images/BeamGlass.png" class="logo">
                <img id="image" class="logo" src="http://jforthdesigns.co.uk/images/BG002.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
            <svg width="1024" height="512">
                <mask id="mask">
                    <path class="st0" d="M206.7,153.4c55,55,144.5,55,199.5,0c0.9-0.9,1.8-1.8,2.2-2.3c1.2-1.3,2.4-2.5,3.5-3.9l-18.2-18.2
                    c-1.3,1.6-2.8,3.1-4.2,4.7c-0.5,0.5-0.9,1-1.4,1.5c-45,45-118.2,45-163.1,0l0,0L206.7,153.4L206.7,153.4z"/>
                    <path class="st0" d="M231.3,128.8c41.4,41.4,108.8,41.4,150.2,0c2-2,3.9-4,5.6-6.2L369,104.4c-1.7,2.2-3.6,4.2-5.6,6.2
                    c-31.4,31.4-82.5,31.4-113.9,0l0,0L231.3,128.8L231.3,128.8z"/>
                    <path class="st0" d="M256.3,103.8c27.6,27.6,72.6,27.6,100.2,0c2-2,3.8-4.1,5.5-6.3l-18.3-18.3c-1.5,2.3-3.4,4.5-5.4,6.5
                    c-17.6,17.6-46.3,17.6-63.9,0l0,0L256.3,103.8L256.3,103.8z"/>
                    <path class="st0" d="M122.3,143.3c0,29.7-26.6,46.2-69.6,46.2c-14.2,0-36.1-1.8-36.6-1.8l0-145.9c0.1,0,18.6-4.2,39.3-4.2
                    c34,0,55.1,11.3,55.1,35.8c0,13.9-6.8,26-19.2,33.8C111,112.2,122.3,123.7,122.3,143.3 M54,171.3c29,0,43.9-9.8,43.9-28.4
                    c0-18.9-14.3-24.8-39.5-24.8c-6.2,0-12.9,0.4-18.5,0.9v51.5C44.4,171,49.3,171.3,54,171.3 M57.9,55.8c-6,0-12.4,0.8-18.1,1.7v44.8
                    l9.8,0.2c26.3,0,37.5-10.7,37.5-26.6C87.1,60.9,76,55.8,57.9,55.8"/>
                    <path class="st0" d="M213.1,39.7c0,0,2,2.7,2,5.1c0,2.1-1.3,8.7-1.8,13.4h-59.5V103h52.3l-1.4,13c-0.3,3.1-2.2,4.9-5.3,4.9h-45.5
                    v48.3h61.4c0,0,2,2.7,2,5.1c0,2.1-1.3,8.7-1.8,13.4h-80.8c-2.4,0-5.1-2.1-5.1-2.1v-146H213.1z"/>
                    <path class="st0" d="M584.6,187.7c-7.4,0-16.5,0.7-19.8,0.7c-2.4,0-5.1-2.1-5.1-2.1l-14.7-95.8c-0.6-3.6-0.8-9.6-0.8-15.1
                    c-0.9,5.2-2.1,10.8-3.4,14.5l-35,97.8c-6.2,0-13.1,0.7-15.7,0.7c-2.4,0-5.1-2.1-5.1-2.1l-34.3-95.7c-1-2.9-1.9-7.4-2.5-11.5
                    c-0.2,3.9-0.5,8-0.8,10.4l-15.2,98.2c-6.3,0-14.1,0.7-16.9,0.7c-2.4,0-5.1-2.1-5.1-2.1L432.1,48c0.7-4.3-0.5-8.3-0.5-8.3
                    c7,0,16.7-0.6,19-0.6c2.4,0,5.1,2,5.1,2l38,98.8c1.7,4.2,3,10,4,15.1c1.1-5.3,2.5-11.2,3.8-14.9l34.1-93.6c1.1-3,0.8-6.8,0.8-6.8
                    c6,0,16.3-0.6,19.5-0.6c2.4,0,5.1,2,5.1,2L584.6,187.7z"/>
                    <path class="st0" d="M339.1,55.8c0,16.5-13.4,29.9-29.9,29.9s-29.9-13.4-29.9-29.9c0-16.5,13.4-29.9,29.9-29.9
                    S339.1,39.3,339.1,55.8"/>
                </mask>
            </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please insert this fiddle in your post so other people can test your code : https://jsfiddle.net/d0cryxrn/

Comment: you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/d0cryxrn/1/ ?

Comment: @PascalGoldbach, I can't edit the original post as it keeps telling me that I can't have anymore links. Apparently, I need more than 10 rep. So, your link will have to suffice for now. Thanks so much for putting it together.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh thanks for the efforts. I just changed a few of the parameters that you had put in place and managed to line it nicely. Thanks for that! The only thing I need now is to be able to fix the image behind the mask, so, that the mask scrolls over it, as opposed to the image scrolling with the page. https://jsfiddle.net/d0cryxrn/3/